# Google maps ApiV2 keeps crashing on android 2.3.7

Tags: android

I build a project by following all the steps provided by Google on its developer's page. The project won't run on my android device running 2.3.7. However, it runs on the eclipse emulator running API level 19. Here's the code for manifest, xml and Java.
Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- OpenGL reference -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- GooglePaly Services Reference -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googmaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Key Reference -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="i don't want to paste the key here. but there is no prob with it" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the code for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Here is the code for Java

```
package my.package;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Please note again that the application runs on the emulator with API 19.
Appreciating help.

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636326/app-not-accepting-gmap-in-xml-file/18636637#18636637

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

and this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Your min sdk is 10. So you need to use `SupportMapFragment` in which case you need to extend `FragmentActivity`.

Use `MapFragment` above api level 11

Note: Test it on a real device which has google play services installed on it. Android 4.2.2 (API 17) Goole api's has google play services. Check point 3 in the below link. So testing on emulator in the below versions will not work as it google maps need google play services.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: It worked. Very useful. I can't believe I spent hours on this.

Comment: @SaadZaheer new problem new post. start a new question with relevant details